# Rails - uploading big images to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, upload, amazon-s3

When I upload an image (on Amazon S3 servers) to a Heroku app from a camera, where the photos have let's say more than 2.5MB, sometimes the app is not processed within 30 seconds and I see on the screen the warning message about **Application Error**.

This is not very user-friendly behavior, how to avoid this acting? I now I can buy an additional dyno, but I am not sure that this is a solution. For file upload I use Paperclip gem.

How do you solve this situation, when users uploads let's say images bigger than 3MB?

Comment: Are you doing any sort of post-processing on the image (like resizing with paperclip) that could be slowing things down? I've had no problem uploading files as large as 25mb using rails on heroku with paperclip.

Comment: Yes, basic resizing for thumbs and middle size images -> which means that I am uploading the original image and from this original size image I am creating 2 another images.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you could do: (in order from best to worst bet)

1. If you have a need to do a lot of post-procesing on images (like resizing them) you can have all of that processing done on a worker dyno using "Delayed Jobs." This way you get a response back much faster, but your alternate or resized versions of the image aren't immediately available, only `:original`. There's a tutorial on it here: http://madeofcode.com/posts/42-paperclip-s3-delayed-job-in-rails
2. You could use [Unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn) or one of it's cousins. While it likely won't fix the image upload issue by itself, it allows you to adjust how long it takes for a request to timeout. As an added bonus it should also speed up the rest of your app.
3. You could try using [Carrier Wave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) with [CarrierWaveDirect](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct) instead of paperclip. This is kind of a shot in the dark as I've never personally used it, but it's supposedly 'better,' which could mean faster? maybe? It sounds like it works in a similar way as Paperclip with delayed jobs.